# Bad to own a directory outside of your home directory?

Tags: permissions, security, directory-structure, home

Some how, can't remember why, I got into the habit of downloading source to the directory `/opt`, which I `chown` to my user/group.

I have this feeling that it is not a good thing to do. Is there anything wrong with owning a directory that is outside of your own home directory?

Comment: Other than the potential to accidentally delete the contents with `rm -r`, not really.

Comment: You'll forget about it when you move to a new computer?

Comment: I have it written into a backup script to save my goods there, so that hopefully shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: If it's your computer you can do as you wish. Generally on Ubuntu and Redhat based system you can roll your own RPM/DEB files as a non-root user and then install them using `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649355/what-does-opt-mean-as-in-the-opt-directory-is-it-an-abbreviation) explains the /opt directory.

Now, your question about the ownership depends on the environment. Is this is a work system, or personal system?

If it's entirely your computer system, download wherever you want to!
That seems like a fine place to maintain ownership of on your own system.

If this is a work computer, it would make more sense to have a more restricted account own that directory, in case other people need the source you're downloading for any reason like using it or auditing it.

Comment: It is totally my own computer, I just thought perhaps it could be some sort of security problem in some unforeseen way. But I'm glad I can keep my behaviour pattern un-changed :)